# canvas.drawPath draws nothing when paint is set to fill?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am trying to draw a triangle on a canvas using `drawPath()` but I am having problems filling the triangle. The following code will draw a triangle just fine if I have the paint set to `STROKE` but when it is set to `FILL` it doesn't draw anything. Is there something I am doing wrong here?

```
    labelArrowBox.reset();

    labelArrowBox.moveTo(labelPosition.x, labelPosition.y);

    float x = labelPosition.x + LABEL_BOX_ARROW_WIDTH / 2;
    float y = labelPosition.y - LABEL_BOX_ARROW_HEIGHT;
    labelArrowBox.lineTo(x, y);
    labelArrowBox.moveTo(x, y);

    x = labelPosition.x - LABEL_BOX_ARROW_WIDTH / 2;
    labelArrowBox.lineTo(x, y);
    labelArrowBox.moveTo(x, y);

    labelArrowBox.lineTo(labelPosition.x, labelPosition.y);
    labelArrowBox.moveTo(labelPosition.x, labelPosition.y);

    labelArrowBox.close();

    Paint arrowBorderPaint = new Paint();
    arrowBorderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    arrowBorderPaint.setDither(true);
    arrowBorderPaint.setColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.leaf_thin_ring));
    arrowBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    canvas.drawPath(labelArrowBox, arrowBorderPaint);
```

Comment: Code looks OK. Are you sure the color you load from resources is not transparent? Also as an optimization, I guess you don't have to `lineTo()` the third line of the triangle if you're calling `close()`.

Comment: Suggest you to first get it working with minimal code with hard-coded co-ordinates and color. Then add other complexities.

Comment: Try to remove all `moveTo` calls except of the first one if question is still actual.

Comment: I'm having this same issue.  Were you ever able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  Remove the `moveTo()` you only nee the `lineTo()`  You shouldn't need these lines: `labelArrowBox.moveTo(x, y);`